# Questiion about the principle of Unit Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and I have question as I dont fully understand the principle of Unit:

`onChecked:(Boolean) -> Unit`

Does it pass the certain data as parameter to other function ( as a Unit)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(Boolean) -> Unit` is a function type.  Before the arrow are the parameters, in this case a `Boolean` and after the arrow is the return type. `Unit` simply means that it doesn't return anything.

See also [this documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-types)

Comment: Nitpick: it doesn't return anything _useful_. (For experienced Kotliners: it does return the `Unit` value, which is the sole value of type [`Unit`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-unit/). You don't need to `return` that explicitly, and you don't usually use it afterwards, but it's there. This distinguishes it from methods returning [`Nothing`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-nothing.html), which never return a value at all — e.g. because they always throw an exception, loop forever, or shut down the program.)

Answer (score 0):

Unit is method signature which actually return nothing like to java void.

for example:
**Kotlin**

```
fun onChecked(isCheck: Boolean): Unit {
  //TODO
}
```

**Java**

```
public void onChecked(boolean isCheck) {
//TODO
}
```

Both are similar

Comment: Thank you @Poran, sorry that I cannot give +rep